# How to list tables whose names not contain numbers with psql?

Tags: oracle, psql

How to list all tables whose name does not contain a number?

I tried along the lines of `\dt [A-z]*` but did not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to negate the `[:digit:]` character class, e.g.

```
\dt public.[^[:digit:]]+
```

says "all tables in schema `public` whose names are composed only of characters that can be anything except digits"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables where NOT REGEXP_LIKE(table_name, '[[:digit:]]')
```

or

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tables where NOT REGEXP_LIKE(table_name, '[[:digit:]]')
```

Comment: I might miss something but neither `dba_tables` nor `user_tables` exists as relation.

Comment: @janosdivenyi:- You are trying to get the table names from your database whose name does not contain a number. Right?

Comment: With `\dt` is get the list of relations and I would like to sort this list by excluding those whose name contains a number. Sorry if I used the wrong terminology.